# ¿Por qué este código no cambia el tamaño del texto, y si quito la línea del DOCTYPE sí?

Tags: html, css, font-size

¿Por qué este código no cambia el tamaño del texto, y si quito la línea del `DOCTYPE` sí?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <body>
      <p id="p1" style="font-size: var(--fs, 30px)">Hola</p>
      <input id="input1" type="range" min="10" max="50" step="1" oninput="output1.innerHTML = this.value; 
      document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--fs',this.value);" />
      <output id="output1">30</output><br />
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: sin el doctype el navegador no activa todos los estandares y puede que: o no encuentra el elemento root del documento o no logra setear la variable ( custom properti --fs ) para el fontsize o el css q depende de esa property no apunta al doc/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes concatenar la unidad de medida **px** en formato texto al nuevo valor para que se cambie por completo en la propiedad **--fs**.

Te lo explico en código `JS` separado del `HTML` para que se vea claro.

```js
function cambiarTamanio(){
  //Capturar los valores de los input
  let input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
  let output1 = document.getElementById('output1');
  //Setear el nuevo valor
  let nuevoValor = input1.value;
  output1.innerHTML = nuevoValor; 
  //Debes concatenar el texto px al nuevo valor
  document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--fs',nuevoValor+'px');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <p id="p1" style="font-size: var(--fs, 30px)">Hola</p>
      <input id="input1" type="range" min="10" max="50" step="1" oninput="cambiarTamanio()" />
      <output id="output1">30</output><br />
   </body>
</html>
```

Ahora, tal como lo tienes, solo debes concatenarlo al final:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <body>
      <p id="p1" style="font-size: var(--fs, 30px)">Hola</p>
      <input id="input1" type="range" min="10" max="50" step="1" oninput="output1.innerHTML = this.value; 
      document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--fs',this.value+'px');" />
      <output id="output1">30</output><br />
   </body>

</html>
```